# How many times is a constructor called when it's overloaded?

Tags: java, constructor

`BankAccount.java`

```
public class BankAccount {
    private double checkingBalance;
    private double savingBalance;
    private static int numberOfAccounts;

    public BankAccount() {
        this(0, 0);
        numberOfAccounts++;
    }
    public BankAccount(double checkingInitial, double savingInitial) {
        this.checkingBalance = checkingInitial;
        this.savingBalance = savingInitial;
        numberOfAccounts++;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfAccounts() {
        return numberOfAccounts;
    }
```

`Test.java`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount account1 = new BankAccount(50, 50);
        BankAccount account2 = new BankAccount(100, 80);
        BankAccount account3 = new BankAccount();

        System.out.println("number of accounts is " + BankAccount.getNumberOfAccounts());
```

I should get `number of accounts is 3` but I'm getting 4. If I instantiate all accounts with the parametrized constuctor, I get 3. If I add `BankAccount account4 = new BankAccount();`, I get 6. Is the default constructor called twice?

Comment: When you call the one that takes no arguments, that one calls the one that takes 2 arguments, via `this(0, 0)`. So `new BankAccount()` ends up incrementing the count twice. Remove `numberOfAccounts++;` from the first constructor, then it will work how you expect

Comment: @Michael Now I understand the problem. Thanks. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
public BankAccount() {
    this(0, 0);
    numberOfAccounts++; // <<<<<
}
```

The explicit call to the other constructor `BankAccount(double, double)` increments `numberOfAccounts`.  Then you increment it again.

Delete the line marked '<<<<'.

In answer to the question in the title:

> How many times is a constructor called when it's overloaded?

There is an explicit call to a constructor in your main program - so 'once'.  But you then wrote code in that constructor to call another constructor.  That is entirely under your control.

Answer (score 0):

The `this()` refers to a constructor of the class itself. You can use `this()` to call the constructor from within the class. In your example, your constructor of signature `BankAccount()` can be referred from within the class as `this()` and `BankAccount(double, double)` from `this(double, double)` signatures. When you instantiate a BankAccount object with `BankAccount()` it calls the `BankAccount(double, double)` which increments numberOfAccounts. Then your caller `BankAccount()` also increments numberOfAccounts. To fix this, simply remove `this(0,0)` from the first constructor. You do not need to initialize the members to 0 because Java does that for you

Comment: You are right in this case. But what if I want to assign other values than 0? The main problem is `numberOfAccounts++` in the constructor with no arguments. Thanks anyway.